# Visual Studio 2012 Dark Colours for Project Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2012, color-scheme

I like the Dark Color Theme for VS2012 but it really annoys me that it doesn´t apply to the Project Properties.

And I can´t find the Properties to change the Color in the Visual-Studio-ColorTheme Editor...

Is it even possible to change these Colours?

Answer (score 0):

GoTo: `Tools -> Options -> Environment (General)`

you will get the option to change color, only if you've installed the Visual-Studio Color theme editor

Comment: yeah I know that, but I can´t find the ColourSettings for the Project-Properties! Do you know if they can be changed?

Comment: well in my VS2012 IDE, after i apply dark theme to it, my project properties automatically darkens.

Comment: wish I could say the same, my dark theme looks like this http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/2469/qqpi.png

Comment: @sine, I've got the same problem.  It looks like a bit of an oversight on behalf of the VS team.

Comment: yes I think so, do you found any solution to get the properties dialog dark?

Comment: @sine unfortunately I've given up.  I suppose I'm going numb to it because I don't notice it any more!  I did find [a way to get rid of the ALL CAPS menu items](http://www.richard-banks.org/2012/06/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2012-all.html) if that annoys you as much as it did me :-)